# Android load Admob ad in static class

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have an application with about 10 activities.
When the user navigates between activities, I would like to share the same ad, so I will avoid the reload of an ad every time the user navigates.(I want to keep the regular refresh time of the ad).

I think of loading the ad into a static class which all activities will use - did anyone here implement such a solution and can share their experience (assuming it's possible)?

If the solution is not possible are there any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not have opportunity to try this out, but I don't see any reason why your solution with static object wouldn't work. You can share static objects among activities, but you need to be aware that in some cases both of them can use one object in same time and that can lead to some conflicts. Your solution should be simple to implement and test out. Let us know what happened.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a game app where I show an interstitial ad after each level. This was my first attempt at ads in an app. I am using the new Google Play Services version.

I decided to group all the AdMob related code in one place so I set up a class and made everything static, similar to what you are describing. The result was that the ads showed, but only some of the time. Also, the app (which until then was running smoothly) became twitchy and subject to inscrutable, unrepeatable bugs.

After several days of hair-pulling, I moved the code into the activity after which the ads were supposed to run and made them the last call in the activity. I also made all the functions and variables non-static. The result was that all the problems magically went away and the game is running without a hitch once again.

On paper, I can't see why the static variables caused these problems, but my advice to anyone thinking of going down this road is to avoid it unless they like inscrutable bugs.

Answer (score 0):

item_banner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_unitID_test">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

```
@ActivityScoped //or singleton
class AdMobRepository @Inject constructor(
  private val context: Context,
  private val podoalRepository: PodoalRepository
) {
  val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

  val staticBanner = ItemBannerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)).apply {
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)
  }.root
}
```

custom view

```
@ActivityScoped //or singleton
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AdmobBanner  : FrameLayout {

@Inject lateinit var adMobRepository: AdMobRepository

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    init(context)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    init(context)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init(context)
}

init {
    addView(adMobRepository.staticBanner.apply { removeSelf() })
}
}

fun View?.removeSelf() {
this ?: return
val parentView = parent as? ViewGroup ?: return
parentView.removeView(this)
}
```

in xml

```
 <AdmobBanner
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```